# Cygwin and gitolite 3. How to set it up on windows?

Tags: git, cygwin, gitolite

I was using [this](http://therightstuff.de/2010/03/28/How-To-Set-Up-A-Git-Server-On-Windows-Using-Cygwin-And-Gitolite.aspx) guide.

Cygwin installation was good and all went well.
Gitolite installation, however, is bad and i can't seem to find the solution to what should i do (neither google helps with that, because everybody link to the page i gave a link to, or everybody talk about old versions of gitolite.)

I have reached the step No. 5 of the "Installing Gitolite" part.
1. I did the part with gitolite cloning ok.
2. The part with installing gitolite was different, but seems to have gone well. `gl-system-install` didn't work, so i used `gitolite/install -ln` as was told by the instructions at [this](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/qi.html) site.
3. This is where everything fails. `gl-setup` doesn't exist anymore, so i used `gitolite setup -pk ~/myName.pub` command. At this stage it first says `Initialized empty Git repository in C:/cygwin64/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git`, right after that i get `fatal: Could not switch to '/home/git': No such file or directory`
It did create the file `/home/git/.gitolite.rc` and i did what the guide told next to do. However when i execute the command `git clone git@gitserver:gitolite-admin.git` after exiting server shell, i get the error
`bash: git-upload-pack: command not found

fatal: could not read from remote repository.`
The repository gitolite-admin.git does exist in `/home/git/repositories`

I would really like to know what am i doing wrong here. I'd like to be able to run git with authentication on windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old guide using Cygwin and gitolite V2.

Nowadays, simply use a regular DOS session with msysgit ([no need for Cygwin anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784743/6309), as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144417/6309)).
For the installation, follow the [official current instructions](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/install.html):
(check that the environment variable `HOME` is defined: [`git-cmd.bat` defines it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17084508/6309))

```
git clone https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/
cd gitolite
gitolite/install -to C:/path/to/bin
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it going. I have istalled msysGit, then i have cloned and installed gitolite, loaded my .pub key and created gitolite-admin. Everything seems to have gone well. But, how do i make it so i can access this git server from anywhere? Seems like no sshd service is running and no guides you have mentioned do that too (unless i missed it). So i think ssh access absence is what is holding me from victory. Any help?

Comment: @user1651105 yes, gitolite itself is just a perl script, you need a listener (https or ssh) to call said Gitolite script. A server like Bitvise (http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd, not free although the evaluation period is quite generous) might be appropriate (more than an ssh server on Cygwin anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17476115/6309)

Comment: @user1651105 or GitWin: https://www.itefix.no/i2/gitwin as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9806428/6309.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to rather use http://gitblit.com/, which provides a full-stack solution for Windows.