# how to setup git repository on localhost

Tags: git, android-studio, localhost, repository

I'm working with my friend on an Android Studio Project. I would like to setup a local git repository on his or my PC so that the repository is created locally and can only be accessed in a local network. unlike git hub where it is available to all. Is there any way that I can setup a localhost git repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hosting a git server on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325089/hosting-a-git-server-on-localhost)

Comment: If you only want a private git repository, you can use Bitbucket or Gitlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325089/hosting-a-git-server-on-localhost)

you can also refer this [link](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/how-to-set-up-a-git-repository-locally/) for more explanation.